# Java applet hides all the HTML contents

Tags: java, html, applet

My first Java applet experience was with `APPLET` and `OBJECT` tags, but I noticed that it isn't a cross-browser solution and decided to use `deployJava.js` as Oracle recommends:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>My First Java Applet</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="1" id="activator1">
  <input type="button" value="2" id="activator2">
  <input type="button" value="3" id="activator3"><br>
  <p>My text<br>
  My text<br>
  My text<br>
  ..........
  My text<br>
  My text<br>
  My text</p>
  <!--
  <applet code="FirstApplet.class" width="260" height="120" id="applet" style="border:dashed 1px red">
  -->
  <!--
  <object type="application/x-java-applet" id="applet">
      <param name="code" value="FirstApplet.class">
  </object>
  -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var attributes = { id:'applet', code:'FirstApplet',  width:260, height:120};
    var parameters = { } ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this approach is that Java applet appears, but all the HTML controls disappear (activator1, activator2, activator3, all the "My text" lines).

When I use `APPLET` tag instead of `deployJava` all the controls coming **after** Java applet disappear, but all the controls coming **before** it remain on page.

How to make the controls remain on page?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but the <applet> tag has been removed from the HTML5 spec, and the Java language has been adding increasing restrictions on applets as a result of the big security scares during Java 6, getting rid of things like self-signing etc. Also, you've not closed your applet tag.

Comment: Try removing `$(document).ready(function(){` (and closing brackets etc.)..  I've seen it work plenty of times *without* that.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: and what about hidden controls on page without any JavaScript?

Comment: *"and what about hidden controls on page"*  What 'hidden controls'? BTW - did it *work*?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: In a pure HTML with java applet (it means: without JavaScript at all) all the HTML elements that are coming after an applet are hidden.